# MySQL Workbench

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, web-development

I'm using Freya for developing web apps in Ruby on Rails with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

The problem is when I install the MySQL Workbench: when I try to perform a query the result is a blank grid.

I'm using Emma for querying (because the console is useful for basic queries but not for complex work)

Comment: I am having the same problem, I've tried various versions of MySQL Workbench, but none is working properly.

Comment: I've tried many solutions but they have not worked. I'm a software developer so this software is important when i have to work with big databases in my daily work. If there is no solution i will have to migrate to another distro.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question (and accept it) instead of adding the solution to the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some many tries, i have make it work by doing this:

I'm using Elementary OS Freya 0.3.1

> Linux 3.19.0-30-generic #34~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:09:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

1. Get the source from for **6.3.4** from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=457803. **THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT BECAUSE WITH OTHER VERSIONS IT DOES NOT WORK.**
2. Navigate to the directory you downloaded it to.
3. tar xvf mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-src.tar.gz
4. cd mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-src
5. wget -O patch-glib.diff http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=21874&bug_id=74147
6. patch -p0 < patch-glib.diff
7. sudo apt-get build-dep mysql-workbench
8. sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
9. cd build
10. cmake .. -DBUILD_CONFIG=mysql_release
11. make
12. sudo make install

Comment: Please make sure to mark this answer as having solved the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Please try to install the latest version from the official website: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1ubu1404-amd64.deb

Comment: Hi ounos, the bug still persist in that version. Any other solution? I've tried to compile it from source applying a "patch" but i have no results.

Comment: This does not work for me either.. However Maximiliano's answer helped me out..

Comment: Dependency is not satisfiable: libctemplate2